# Hibernate ClassNotFoundException with Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, hibernate, classnotfoundexception

Added another project (Java project) to classpath, which uses Hibernate and i get this error:
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

My project is a Dynamic Web Project. When i tried the same with a java project, it worked.
Both have hibernate.cfg.xml included, so didn't forget that.
Something to do with Dynamic Web Project classpath and its peculiarity.
Any ideas?

Comment: Found an answer here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=998711&view=next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hibernate jar is missing in the class path (referenced libs or WebContent/WEB-INF/lib).